# Torch Lua cannot find default terminal on mac

Tags: macos, lua, torch, macos-sierra

I updated my OS to mac OS, and then updated lua and other packages with a `brew upgrade`. Now I can't use gnuplot in lua, I receive this error:

```
Can not find any of the default terminals for mac. You can manually set terminal by gnuplot.setterm("terminal-name")
```

Note: I am using iTerm2 as terminal, if that's any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually with gnuplot itself, not lua or torch.
I just reinstalled it with x11 and it worked:

```
brew uninstall gnuplot; brew install gnuplot --with-x11
```